# discord.py bot cant use message and ctx in the same def

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to do a certain thing when a certain user types a command. for example if a user with an id of  `123456` sends a command I want to `await ctx.send('hi')` and if a user with an id of `7890` sends the same command to use `await ctx.send('hi2')`.

this is what I've tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(message, ctx):

    if message.author.id == "id goes here":
        await ctx.send('hi')
    elif message.author.id == "id goes here":
        await ctx.send('hi but other')
```

but what it does when I run the command `!test` is this:

```
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khvede1a/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/khvede1a/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/khvede1a/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 786, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/khvede1a/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/khvede1a/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

what has worked is if I remove `ctx` and just print it to console it works just fine. but if `ctx` and `message` are in the same def they won't work for some reason. Passing it to another def could be the solution but im kindaaa noobie in here sorry for that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == YOUR_ID:
        await ctx.send('Hi!')
    elif ctx.author.id == YOUR_ID:
        await ctx.send('Hey!')
```

Where `YOUR_ID` is the ID (an integer value) of the user that the bot is allowed to respond to.

Comment: @DatoKhvedelidze no prob! Please mark this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: sure ! 10 minutes have to pass me to mark it